# Google Drive API upload 1 fiile from php

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

on output when open page -

File ID: 1qG8tteyVhAbB_rbu_VUvaE9ReqnSjEAh...

But on google drive no new files are created. I want upload file to cron but now i want only download test.pdf and end.

```
require_once './google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\Drive;

function uploadBasic()
{
    try {
        $client = new Client();
        //$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->setAuthConfig('./google-api-php-client/1710-6c50418be6b2.json');
        $client->addScope(Drive::DRIVE);
        $driveService = new Drive($client);
        
        $fileMetadata = new Drive\DriveFile(array(
                'parents' => ['225qhcKKyf8Ot0IhrRxRtqgHNTxLV1LiyI'],
                'name' => 'test.pdf',
                'mimeType' => 'application/pdf'));
        
        $mimeType=mime_content_type($fileMetadata);
        $content = file_get_contents('https://example.com/test.pdf');
        $file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array([
                    'data' => $content,
                    'mimeType' => 'application/pdf',
                    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
                    'fields' => 'id']));
        printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
        return $file->id;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Error Message: ".$e;
    }   
}

uploadBasic();
```

Comment: Would close voter please comment on what clarity they need?

Comment: Dont edit your question and change your code in this manner. You are changing the issue.

Answer (score 4):

## how to debug issue

The fastest way to debug this is to do a [File.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list).  This will tell you if in fact the file was uploaded.

You are not setting parents yin your meta data, so the file will have been uploaded to the root directory.

## service account

Remember if you are using a service account that the files are uploaded into the service accounts google drive account, not your personal drive account.

To upload to your personal drive account you would need to create a directory on your drive account, share that directory with your service account using the service account email address. The service account email address can be found in the json key file its the only one with an @.

Then set parents in the meta data to the folder on your drive account

```
$fileMetadata = new Drive\DriveFile(array(
                'parents' => { 'FolderId' }
                'name' => 'ASB-Background-3.png'));
```

## File 0 size error after edit

You edited your question.  It originally stated you were doing this

```
  $content = file_get_contents('./google-api-php-client/ASB-Background-3.png');
```

It is bad practice to update your question and change your code. It changes the answer to your question and in this case your error message.

That being said From the documentation for [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

> file_get_contents — Reads entire file into a string

There is nothing in the documentation that states that this method could load a file from a url.  So your edit changing to a URL is probably not going to work.

```
file_get_contents('https://example.com/test.pdf');
```

Your file is uploading with 0 because your not giving it a file. Download that file on to the machine running it and then send it, or write our own method which will accept a url and return a string file conents.

## upload image

Files are uploaded in two parts first the fileMetadata and then the file itself.

MimeType must be properly set to that of the file you are uploading. file_get_contents will only work on a file that is currently accessible by your code.

If the file size is 0 make sure

1. to check the most recent uploaded file.  every create will create a new file.
2. ensure that your code has access to the file you are uploading.
3. make sure the mimeType is correct.

[Sample.](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#simple)

```
try {
    $client = new Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->addScope(Drive::DRIVE);
    $driveService = new Drive($client);
    $fileMetadata = new Drive\DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'photo.jpg'));
    $content = file_get_contents('../files/photo.jpg');
    $file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array([
        'data' => $content,
        'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart',
        'fields' => 'id']));
    printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
    return $file->id;
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Error Message: ".$e;
}
```

Comment: perfect, created file but him 0 byte....

Comment: maybe do you know why?

Comment: I would delete the file and try to upload it again. If it still doesnt work check your file_get_contents section.  Its not uploading the data, but there is noting i can see wrong with your code off hand.

Comment: maybe try hard setting the mime type.  rather then using that method just to test it.

Comment: i test to file_get_contents full link to file(on browser open him its pdf) and all ok.. i test write 'mimeType' => 'application/pdf', and did not help for me(   created null file and end(

Comment: edit code for new, him upload file but him 0 size...

Comment: Thats because your not uploading a file your giving it a url it i dont think that is supported by the method you are using.

Comment: but for url i have pdf file

Comment: Then download the pdf file and place it on the machine that the code resides on.  The add the path  file_get_contents('./example.com/test.pdf');  You cant download from a http url using file_get_contents.

Comment: file place on ftp server (web site) and i want him upload to google drive.

Comment: then run the code from the ftp server. or write some code that downloads the file from the ftp server to the server where you are uploading from and send it that way.  file_get_contents only operates on a file

Comment: i run file, him upload file but him 0 size... i test now on png. edit to mimeType and url where image, and again 0size

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the most recently uploaded file. every time you run this your going to get a new file.

Comment: yes, new code run... test now on 'test.jpg' + edit link to this image+mimeType, but download test.jpg with 0 size